# Replace misspelled word in figures in pdf

Tags: pdf

I have a pdf-file with lots of figures. I now noticed that I misspelled a word in many of these figures (the same word is used in all these figures). The pdf was obtained by Latex, so the brute-force option would be to edit all figures one by one, and recompile. However that would take a lot of time, so my question is if there is a faster way to replace the word automatically with the correct spelled word in these figures in a pdf?

Comment: and the figures are latex too? or included from a different source as eps or something?

Comment: Generally replacing text in pdfs is not as easy as one might believe. Can you share a sample pdf and indicate which content to replace by which other?